# direct root domain from godaddy to aws ec2 balancer

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I know this question has been asked in quite a few places even on amazon's form such as

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223727

I followed the documentation too but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

Can someone please give me an idea what I might be doing wrong?

I bought a new domain in godaddy. In dns management, I removed the only A record in it, now there's no A record in godaddy's dns management.

In aws, I created a load balancer and I used the dns name load balancer created which works quite well if I just paste it into a browser such as `balancerName-1230.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com`

I followed the steps to create a hosted zone in route 53, created a new record set

[image]

I tried in my browser for `example.com` and I get `This site can’t be reached`

P.S. while creating the A record, I did not type in anything in the name field to leave it as the root domain.

Is there anything I am missing that's why it's not working? Anyone has idea about this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup the Name Servers in GoDaddy to use Route 53.

Login to your GoDaddy account. Select Domains and then select your domain name.

For your Settings, click on Manage under Nameservers. Then replace the four name servers with the Route 53 name servers.

Once this is complete, you will need to wait about 24 hours for the TTL on the name servers to timeout and be updated globally.

Comment: It usually doesn't take 24 hours, but sometimes it can.

Comment: @Tim - very true. The time depends on what is set in the GoDaddy name servers TTL and if the other DNS Servers around the world respect the TTL. Some people expect the switch over to be instant which is not the case for DNS. Since this is his own domain name, he already has pre-cached the DNS servers in his area ...

Comment: thx thx, let  me give it a try.  Would it somehow take more than 24 hours though?

Comment: If you've accessed the domain name the name servers will be cached somewhere. As John said it depends on the TTL of the name servers. Can't tell you since you've blanked out your details, but mxtoolbox or network tools can often tell you

Comment: Some people set the TTL for name servers to a week. Look in your GoDaddy console and check. Normally, when I am about to make a DNS change, I change the TTL on the entries that I plan to change to be very small like 60 seconds. Then I wait until the current TTL expires. This way I plan ahead and make the changes once the short TTL comes into play. After testing and verifying my changes, I reset the TTL back to something normal like one day to reduce DNS traffic.

Comment: @JohnHanley ah, I just want to make sure, since the nameserver is not by godaddy anymore.  Actually I need to go into the aws and change where those 4 nameserver's ttl is right?

Comment: If you have pointed your domain to Route 53's name servers, then change the TTL in Route 53. Have you made this change since your posted the question?

Comment: @JohnHanley yup, I just made the changes in godaddy's nameserver into the `ns.blah.co` (the 4 ns provided by `route53`)

Comment: @JohnHanley perfect :D thx for the answer. But I got more questions though, totally new to load balancer

Comment: Start up a new question and we will be happy to help.